# How to navigate from one view to another in Swift UI on a click of button

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5

I want to push from one view to another in SwiftUI on a click of button. Likewise we navigate from one controller to another controller in storyboard.

But in SwiftUI how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that.

The first one is with "isActive" binding.

```
struct ViewA: View {

    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: NextView(),
                               isActive: $isActive) {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isActive = true
                        }) {
                            Text("Push Next View")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You place the view which you want to push in the NavigationLink's destination. 
The second way is again with NavigationLink, but using "tag" and "selection". There the navigation is activated when the selection matches the tag.

Comment: This is my code:

                Button(action:{
                            NavigationLink(destination: TableView()) {
                                Text("Show Detail View")
                            }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
                }){
                    Text("Navigate")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green).background(Color.purple)
                    
                }

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it by using NavigationLink

**What is NavigationLink ?**

NavigationLink: Creates a button on the right hand side of each cell and triggers presentation to the detail view

Apple Link: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

**Sample Projects**

Apple 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Github
https://github.com/appbrewery/H4X0R-News-iOS13-SwiftUI-Completed

**How to Implement:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: "LandmarkDetail" is your destination view.

You can also download the sample project from apple (link mentioned above) to understand it clearly